# Win10: Using symbolic links in the PATH variable

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables, symlink

Here's the deal. I want to use a symbolic link to the latest installed Java version and create a symbolic link. The PATH variable shall contain the symbolic link as entry. The link is not resolved, though. Why?

Example:

```sh
$> dir C:\Program\ Files\Java
C:\Program\ Files\Java\jdk-1.14.1\
C:\Program\ Files\Java\jdk-latest.lnk  # link to jdk-1.14.1

$> echo %PATH%
#...
C:\Program\ Files\Java\jdk-latest\bin

$> java --version
The command "java" is either written wrong or couldn't be found.
```

Comment: A .lnk shell link is not a filesystem symbolic link. It's a binary file that the high-level Windows shell API processes. It doesn't even have to target a real file or directory; it can be anything in the shell namespace.

Comment: You want either a directory junction (i.e. a bind mountpoint) created in CMD via `mklink /j jdk-latest jdk-1.14.1` or a directory symlink created via `mklink /d jdk-latest jdk-1.14.1` (this is a relative link; you could also link to the absolute path). A bind mountpoint can be created without any special privilege. Creating a symlink requires SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege. If this privilege is not assigned explicitly to the user or one of the user's non-administrator groups, then it's only available by elevating to full administrator access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[New-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.3&preserve-view=true) cmdlet with `-ItemType SymbolicLink` can be used to create symbolic link to file or folder.

Suppose, you have 2 folders containing 2 different versions of nodejs

```
node-v14.18.0-win-x64
node-v14.20.0-win-x64
```

We need one symbolic link, say `rel` which will point to one of the nodejs folders.

Add `C:\Program\Files\nodejs\rel` to PATH environment variable

Point rel to node v14.18.0

```
New-Item -Type SymbolicLink -Path .\rel -Target .\node-v14.18.0-win-x64 -Force
```

Verify node version

```
PS C:\Users\pvaddepa> node -v
v14.18.0
```

Use `-Force` to update the symbolic link to point to node v14.20.0.

```
New-Item -Type SymbolicLink -Path .\rel -Target .\node-v14.20.0-win-x64 -Force
```

Verify the node version

```
PS C:\Users\pvaddepa> node -v
v14.20.0
```

See [New-Item example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.3&preserve-view=true#example-7-create-a-symbolic-link-to-a-file-or-folder) .